# const access and non-const access

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have a class which internally owns a vector of foo

```
class bar {
  private:
    vector<Foo> foos_;
}
```

Now I want to design public access to this vector. I am thinking of two versions of the function:

```
Foo& getFoo(int index) {
  // first do size checking, return ref
  return foos[index];
}
```

and

```
const Foo& getFoo(int index) const {
  // first do size checking, return const reference
  return foos[index];
}
```

Any downside of this approach? One obvious downside is I copy the almost identical code simply twice. Is there a better way to do this?

----- edit -----
the second accessor forgets const, updated

Comment: why not call the non-const function from within the const one?

Comment: Because you can't call a non-const method from a const method. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: Avoid the situation. You have a design flaw.

Comment: A common technique goes like this: `Foo& getFoo(int index) { const bar* constThis = this; return const_cast<Foo&>(constThis->getFoo(index)); }`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Then so does `std::vector`. Its `operator[]` uses the same approach.

Comment: I'm not contradicting anyone trying to make things work.

Comment: Is what @IgorTandetnik proposed a reasonable approach?

Comment: second version seems to be better as you don't want people to change your private data member from getter function if this will be subscript operator overload then first version will be better

Comment: No idea whom that is. Doesn't matter. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @TedLyngmo This seems like standard practice in C++ to me.  How would *you* design things better?

Comment: @Kapil I think you misunderstand.  The poster isn't asking *which* version to use; it's asking how best to have *both*.

Comment: @jamesdlin Really? You don't see a design flaw? Is that how you would design things?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Exactly what do you consider to be a design flaw here?  Having both `const` and non-`const` accessors?  If I were implementing a STL-like container class, then that's a requirement.  Or do you mean that it's a design flaw of the C++ language that there isn't an easy way to make a `const` and non-`const` accessors leverage each other?  That I could agree with.  And again, if you have better suggestions, please provide them.

Comment: :-) Nope ... I'd back even further back ...

Answer (score 1):

Having both const and non-const accessors is somewhat common in C++.  There is no language feature to combine the code for both--you really do need to write it twice.

By the way,  you don't need to do bounds checking yourself, you can use `foos_.at(index)` instead of `foos_[index]` and then you'll have automatic bounds checking.